# How to setup React Router in a sub folder with an ambiguous path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react router and was wondering if anyone has any idea on how to set it up in the following situation.

Say we have a php application running on `'http://www.example.com'`. On a specific route we have a react application running e.g `'http://www.example.com/misc/stats/'` This app has two routes `'/'` and an ambiguous one `'/:user'`.

I'm using react router 4. How do I serve the app from that folder and have routes be relative to that url. At the moment I've tried setting the `basename` like so.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router basename={basePath} history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  root,
);
```

Then in `<App />` I have a simple setup.

```
const Test1 = () => (<div>Test1</div>);
const Test2 = () => (<div>Test2</div>);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/">A</Link> | <Link to="/b">B</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/a" component={Test1} />
          <Route path="/b" component={Test2} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any thoughts? Futhermore, my biggest concern is how to handle direct url's to *users* For example to `'http://www.example.com/misc/stats/johndoe'` There is of course no johndoe folder, the app is served from the `'stats'` folder. I believe I would need to send all requests to `/misc/stats/(*)` to `/misc/stats/index.html` but i'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to add a param - so it would look something like this:

`<Route path="/misc/stats/:user" component={Test1} />`

You could define the link like this:

```
<Link to=`/misc/stats/${user}`>B</Link>
```

`${user}` is of course the variable you'll pass the link which will contain the user's name.

What you would do then is have the component `Test1` consume that param via `this.props.match.params.user` and do what you need to do with that user to customize the view.